# column buttons missing from datatables column visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We have a datatable that looks like this. As you can see, when you click the column visibility button only a line is appearing:

[image]

```
var dataTableDefaults ={
    columnDefs: [
        {
            "targets": -1,
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": "noSearchOrSort",
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": "noSort",
            "orderable": false,
        },
        {
            "targets": "noSearch",
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": "invisible",
            "visible": false
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend : 'colvis',
            columns : ":visible"
        }
    ],
    order: [[0, 'asc']],
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    language: {
        loadingRecords: 'Loading...',
        emptyTable: 'No Data available'
    },
    pagingType:     'full_numbers',
    processing: true
};

var cols = [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "bVisible" : false }
];


jointDefaults = $.extend(true,{},dataTableDefaults);
jointDefaults.columns = cols
$('#table').DataTable(
        $.extend(
            jointDefaults,
            {
                bServerSide:    true,
                bProcessing:    true,
                sAjaxSource:    'ajax.php',
                fnServerData:   function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    aoData.push(
                                {
                                    name:   'gt', 
                                    value:  1 
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'mode', 
                                    value: pageMode 
                                },
                    );

                    $.ajax({
                        dataType:   'json', 
                        type:       'GET', 
                        url:        sSource, 
                        data:       aoData, 

                        success:    function (response) {
                                fnCallback(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        )
    );
```

Why are the show/hide buttons on the column visibility not appearing?

Comment: Maybe something to do with 

columns : ":visible"

I can't find anything in their api that shows using :visible as a value there.  Have you looked at the console to see if any errors are generated?

Comment: I checked and there were no javascript errors. I don't think there is an error in the dataTableDefaults section because that is used by other datatables that are working correctly.

Comment: Maybe another script is causing a conflict on this particular page?